# 360 degree photo viewer

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation, photo

I have a photos that is taken by 360 degree lance now does anyone know how to create 360 degree photo viewer ?

please don't send the link of already developed softwares , it would be better if someone has
the road map / example code / articles.

Preferred Technologies Could be 
Java/Flash/Flex/HTML 5 / javascript

Comment: This is a pretty complex task, as you need to adjust the perspective, size, rotation, vignette, hue and brightness of every image in a way every image will look the same. Why do you absolutely want to develop it for yourself?

Comment: Ya it is a pretty complex task and even i don't know from where to start ,by the way a client wants to develop that and want to add more features like cropping and mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I haven't done it myself yet but it basically boils down to projecting the photos you have to some camera surrounding primitive.

Easiest would be a cube but this will probably result in not so good results especially at the edges and corners. Better would be a sphere on which the images are projected.

But basically, adding 3D-primitives and mapping textures on it should easily be capable with Java or Flash. If you try to program it for browsers, have a look at [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL). This would be a more future-oriented approach that doesn't need Flash... And it already provides good methods for texture mapping on surfaces.

If by 360° you only mean the horizontal plane you could also use a cylinder, which makes it much easier than projecting on spheres. You'll just need a wide panorama photo that goes around completely and map it to the cylinder.

So basically no matter which primitive you choose you'll need to position your camera within this primitive, project the photos to the primitive and implement some controls that allow the user to rotate the camera freely.

Can you provide any example photos? This would make it easier to find a way to solve your problem and find a good way of projecting the texture...

Hope that helps... if not, keep asking...